# Why do we sometimes format expressions in question form?

Tags: grammar, expressions

For example, from Some Like it Hot,

> Boy, would I love to borrow a cup of that Sugar.

why did he put it in a question format?

Answer (score 1):

Although that format is very common in questions, it's not exclusive to questions. It's a perfectly valid statement. There are many ways to say the same thing. Consider:

> I have always liked seafood.

Which can be reworded as:

> Always have I liked seafood.

The second format isn't as common, but it's simply valid English. I don't think there's any special reason beyond that. You just have to phrase the rest of the sentence differently when you move certain parts around, like verbs.

Some more examples:

> Heavy was the rain that followed.
>
> Deep into the woods she walked.
>
> Short lived was the vacation.
>
> Intriguing was the question asked on StackExchange.
>
> Bizarre are the rules of the English language.

EDIT: I would like to add that when something like your example shows up, it's likely an artistic choice. "Boy, would I love to [x]" has different emphasis than "Boy, I would love to [x]," and it might just flow better depending on the sentence.

Comment: It might be grammatical to use say 'Heavy was the rain that followed,' and Tolkien was a master of the form, but I'd mark 'Intriguing was the question asked on StackExchange.' wrong in an English essay 90+% of the time. It's totally unidiomatic. 'Boy, would I love to borrow a cup of that sugar.' is colloquially quite acceptable, on the other hand.